# How to fetch/provide CSRF token in a REST call from a client using .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, csrf

I'm trying to make a `REST` call (to an `SAP Netweaver API` method).
The API requires a CSRF token to be sent with the call.

When using a REST client manually, I can send a request to get the token (using an HTTP GET containing the header `"X-CSRF-Token: Fetch"` and another one containing the encoded credentials for basic authentication ("Authorization: Basic ").
The response contains a header with the CSRF token.
In the second call, I provide the token in the header `"X-CSRF-Token: <token>"` and the same encoded credentials.
The second call succeeds, I get the result of the rest call.

Now, I'd like to call the same API programmatically.

> 1. Do I need to perform this roundtrip to get the token at all, or is there a way to do it automatically?
> 2. If so, how do I detect that I have to fetch and send the token? (whether AntiForgeryToken handling is enabled on the server side?)
> 3. How do I actually get the token and add it to the REST call?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you use token(JWT/CSRF Token), you need to read from response header at the first time. Then you can use SessionStorage to store it. Before making any request to your API, you need to add JWT/CSRF Token to Http Headers manually. In angular, you can use http interceptor, add your logic in 1 place. So you don't need to add/retrieve in multiple places